# Click home icon with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to click the home icon in some Espresso tests via:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.home)).perform(click());
```

This works fine for Android > 3.0 - but fails for older versions as `appcompat` does not seem to use this id for this element then. What is a good approach to do what I want to do?

Comment: Wondering if you found an answer to this?

Comment: AFAIR not really - I think I worked around this then. Might be worth a try if this changed in the most recent appcompat though

Comment: Just found a solution (for me at least). See answer.

Comment: @ligi Hello! Can you change the accepted answer, please?

Comment: @sunlover3 ack - just changed the accepted answer to yours  - you are right - this solution is better. Does it work for appcompat and native?

Comment: @ligi Great! Thank you. It should work, because the OS developers who work on this part should not change these ids. Otherwise, all the tests developed will crash. For the moment, all my tests regarding this part are working.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To not depend on the app locale, you can use the code from [Matt Logan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351432/matt-logan) by replacing "Navigate up" with `R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description`:

```
onView(withContentDescription(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description)).perform(click());
```

This helped me a lot because I have an app in more than 5 languages and I had to act like this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted one only works on English devices... #fail

Comment: Thanks. I always think of using general commands, so this is why I searched for the android native string id. Good luck!

Comment: I would like to help you. Can you tell me how did you receive this error? You must be careful that before calling onView on any view, be sure that nothing overlaps it (like a dialog or some other screen). My code works pretty fine, you have a mistake in your code structure.

Comment: I have the same problem as @AutonomousApps. how can I check to see of anything is overlapping? Shouldn't the withContentDescription bring the view to the top level view that contains the Navigate up button?

Comment: I found solution without workaround. Here: val upButton = onView(allOf(instanceOf(ImageButton::class.java), withParent(withId(toolBar))))

Comment: for people using androidx, it's `androidx.appcompat.R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description`

Comment: with navigation component, this is only working in English, when I try in French it fails. @AthaMit's answer works for both languages

Comment: @OyaCanli I'm sure that since 2016 the things might have changed. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 33):

Use the `withContentDescription()` `Matcher`:

```
onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());
```

Comment: This works, however, this may fail on devices that are not set to English

Comment: If you look for this log in your failures in your language: `+------->ImageButton{id=-1, desc=Navigate up,`, the `desc` value will be the translated description in the device's current language. I'd imagine that's buried somewhere within the `android.R.string` declarations, but I haven't been able to ferret out where it's hidden.

Comment: Not sure why the different language thing is a big deal, unless you're running your automated tests on devices set to a different language. Even in this case, you could just `switch` on the device's default `Locale` to set the appropriate "Navigate up" translation.

Comment: Use with caution, because: _1)_ apparently in **4.3** content description is **"<action bar title>, Navigate up"** and matching will fail. _2)_ You can have more than one view with a such description. In particular, only `onView(allOf(withContentDescription(containsString("Navigate up")), isClickable())).perform(click())` works for me.

Answer (score 21):

I had trouble navigating back from one Activity to another, but then I found top-level actions:

```
Espresso.pressBack();
```

Comment: Please notice that back navigation is not the same as up navigation: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 14):

I found a real solution to this issue. By using the hierarchyviewer I found that the toolbar looks like this:
[image: hierarchyviewer screenshot]

This means we could match the hamburger icon (not back button) like this:

```
onView(withContentDescription("Open navigation")).perform(click());
```

But a better solution to me was to find out that the hamburger icon is the only ImageButton and a direct child view of the v7 Toolbar. So I wrote a helper method to match it:

```
public static Matcher<View> androidHomeMatcher() {
    return allOf(
        withParent(withClassName(is(Toolbar.class.getName()))),
        withClassName(anyOf(
            is(ImageButton.class.getName()),
            is(AppCompatImageButton.class.getName())
    )));
}

@Test
public void clickHamburgerIcon() throws Exception {
    onView(androidHomeMatcher()).perform(click());
    // ...
}
```

This solution is better because it should match the view no matter which locale you use in your test. :-)

EDIT: Note that Toolbar might be android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar or android.widget.Toolbar - depending on your use case!

EDIT: The support lib version 24.2.0 uses AppCompatImageButton instead of ImageButton, so I added it, too.

EDIT: You have to import the correct methods to get this to work. Here are the imports used:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withClassName;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withParent;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
```

Comment: For Kotlin devs, import `is` using something like `import org.hamcrest.Matchers.\`is\` as _is`.

Comment: The only that worked for my case. I was trying to close a search view.

Answer (score 5):

```
Espresso.pressBack();
```

Or

```
onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having problems with "Navigate up" in an emulator, this worked for me:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(ViewActions.pressMenuKey());
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static Matcher<View> navigationIconMatcher() {
    return allOf(
            isAssignableFrom(ImageButton.class),
            withParent(isAssignableFrom(Toolbar.class)));
}

@Test
public void clickHamburgerIcon() throws Exception {
onView(navigationIconMatcher()).perform(click());
// ...
}
```

this works always!

Comment: yes, it works, but only with `Toolbar` widget. For system navigation you should choose another solution

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is opening / closing the drawer, I recommend using the Espresso contrib library:

```
onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());
```

Answer (score 2):

To press back View:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(pressBack());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:
I couldnt find `R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description`, maybe it has to do with androidx. I'm not sure about this.
Instead I used `R.string.nav_app_bar_navigate_up_description`
The code looks like this:

```
onView(withContentDescription(R.string.nav_app_bar_navigate_up_description)).perform(click())
```

Comment: Thanks! The accepted anwser only works in English for me since I migrated to Jetpack navigation. This solution worked in French as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
//click on the navigation up button to go back to the list
onView(withContentDescription(getToolbarNavigationContentDescription())).perform(click());
```

Methods:

```
private String getToolbarNavigationContentDescription() {
    return TestUtils.getToolbarNavigationContentDescription(
            activityTestRule.getActivity(), R.id.toolbar);
}

public static String getToolbarNavigationContentDescription(
        @NonNull Activity activity, @IdRes int toolbarId) {
    Toolbar toolbar = activity.findViewById(toolbarId);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        return (String) toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("No toolbar found.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onView(withContentDescription("Open navigation drawer")).perform(click())

this helped me

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can call:

```
pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
```

Answer (score -3):

Add `onbackpress` in your activity, and use:

```
onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());
```