# How do you test the action bar back button with espresso?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-espresso

I'm trying to learn how to test my Android project including my navigation. I have implemented a navHost fragment as a NavController, and use it to set up my action bar back button for moving through my fragments. I'm not sure how to access this back button so that I can test it through espresso.

Here is the relevant code from the onCreate function from the main activity:

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
```

Here is a related stackoverflow page but they are asking about the home button and I am trying to use the back button: [How do I test the home button on the Action Bar with Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527988/how-do-i-test-the-home-button-on-the-action-bar-with-espresso)

Here is my test so far (my android app is for ordering a sandwich):

```
@Test
fun testNavigation() {
    //check starting screen
    onView(withId(R.id.welcomeConstraint)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    //push button
    onView(withText(R.string.order_now)).perform(click())
    //check next screen
    onView(withId(R.id.order_constraint)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

 
    //TO-DO: check action bar back button


    //click bread
    onView(withText(R.string.wheat)).perform(click())
    //click sandwich
    onView(withText(R.string.panini)).perform(click())
    //click submit
    onView(withText(R.string.submit)).perform(click())

    //this is an issue: need to click submit twice
    onView(withText(R.string.submit)).perform(click())

    //check next screen
    onView(withId(R.id.recieptConstraint)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

I'm new to both Android and testing, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working answer I found if locale is English after checking the automatic espresso testing:

```
val imageButton = onView(
            Matchers.allOf(
                withContentDescription("Navigate up"),
                isDisplayed()
            )
        )
        
imageButton.perform(click())
```

If the app is multilingual then use:

```
val imageButton = onView(
            Matchers.allOf(
                withContentDescription(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description),
                isDisplayed()
            )
        )
        
imageButton.perform(click())
```

Comment: this link is probably the even more correct way to handle it: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing

Comment: If you're like me and use `androidx` then you won't be able to find `R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description` use  `androidx.navigation.ui.R.string.nav_app_bar_navigate_up_description` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following.

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.home)).perform(click())
```

Comment: this did not work because it returned this error: `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id is <android:id/home>`
I'm assuming this is because I have not enabled the home button.

Comment: Yeah, can you try setting the following in your `ToolBar` and then check again? Thank you! `toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`