# Espresso:No views in hierarchy found matching with id: android:id/home

Tags: android, android-testing

When i run my test case,I got follow exception .

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: android:id/home

This is my TestCase code.

```
 public void nav_to_alarm_test(){
        onView(withId(R.id.navigation_notifications)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.rl_reminder)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.item_test)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(android.R.id.home)).perform(click());//throw exception here
        onView(withId(android.R.id.home)).perform(click());
    }
```

This is 
 android.R.id.home,belongs to button provided by ActionBar

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.item_test:
                startActivityForResult(CreateOrUpdateReminderActivity.class,CMD_ADD_REMINDER);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

why can't find views in hierarchy for resource id android.R.id.home?
I have Google my problem, but answers isn't what i want.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462828/1083957) help you?

Comment: @azizbekian I found a solution in his answer ,thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same question like here([click home icon with espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985181/click-home-icon-with-espresso/35462828#35462828))
what solve my question is this line

```
Espresso.pressBack();
```

Comment: be careful it may kill the activity